# Generating a column showing the number of distinct values between consecutive days

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with the following format:

| UserId | Date | BookId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-15 | 10 |
| 1 | 2022-07-16 | 11 |
| 1 | 2022-07-16 | 12 |
| 1 | 2022-07-17 | 12 |

From this table, what I want to obtain is the number of new BookId on each consecutive day for each user. For example, based on the table above, the user read two new books on 2022-07-16, and did not read a new book on 2022-07-17 since  s/he read it already on the previous day. Here is the expected outcome:

| UserId | 2022-07-16 | 2022-07-17 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |

I feel like this task could be done by grouping data by UserId and Date, and then using the apply lambda function. However, I could not manage it. I ended up with the following code, which uses the for loop. Is there a way to achieve this without a loop with a shorter code?

```
df = studentAnswers.groupby('StudentId')
df.apply(findObjDiff)

def findObjDiff(df):
    print(df.StudentId.head(3))
    dataDict = {}
    dates = list(df.Date)
    dates.sort()
    for d in dates:
        ixNext = dates.index(d) + 1
        if(ixNext > len(dates)):
            break
        dateNext = dates[ixNext]
        objListPrev = set(df[df.Date == d].ObjectiveId)
        objListNext = set(df[df.Date == dateNext].ObjectiveId)
        dataDict[df.StudentId] = {dateNext : {'Different': len(objListPrev - objListNext)}}

    return dataDict
```

Comment: Why don't you report the count for 2022-07-15?

Comment: @mozway because there is no earlier day before it. but, yes could be reported as well.

Comment: I have a doubt on the logic, do you only want to consider the previous day for duplicates?

Comment: @mozway, what I mean is the day just before the current day. Maybe, the user did not read a book on some days. So, there might be gaps, such as: 2022-07-11, 2022-07-13, 2022-07-15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and a [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
(df.assign(count=~df['BookId'].duplicated())
   .pivot_table(index='UserId', columns='Date', values='count', aggfunc='sum')
   .astype(int).reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Considering only consecutive days for the duplicates:

```
s = df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']))['BookId'].agg(set)

(df.assign(count=(s-s.shift(1, freq='D')).str.len().to_numpy())
   .pivot_table(index='UserId', columns='Date', values='count', aggfunc='sum')
   .astype(int).reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Output:

```
   UserId  2022-07-15  2022-07-16  2022-07-17
0       1           1           2           0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```
(df.loc[df.sort_values('Date')
.groupby(['UserId','BookId'])['Date'].transform(lambda x: x.diff().dt.days.ne(1))]
.groupby(['UserId','Date'])['BookId'].nunique()
.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['UserId'].unique(),df['Date'].unique()],names = ['User',None]),fill_value=0)
.unstack())
```

Output:

```
      2022-07-15  2022-07-16  2022-07-17
User                                    
1              1           2           0
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'UserId': [1, 1, 1, 1],
                   'Date': ['2022-07-15', '2022-07-16', '2022-07-16', '2022-07-17'],
                   'BookId': [10, 11, 12, 12],
                   })

r = (df.drop_duplicates(subset='BookId')
       .pivot_table(index='UserId', columns='Date', values='BookId', aggfunc='count')
       .reset_index()
       .rename_axis(columns=''))

m = ~df['Date'].isin(r.columns)

for dat in df[m]['Date']:
    r[dat] = 0

print(r)
```

**Result**

```
   UserId  2022-07-15  2022-07-16  2022-07-17
0       1           1           2           0
```